# Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90

Tags: r, glmnet

it just reports:

> Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90.

i don't know why.

```
    x.m <- data.matrix(train[,c(1:43)])
    x.m [is.na(x.m)] <- 0
    y.m <- train$NPL
    cv.m <-data.matrix(cv)
    set.seed(356)


    cvfit.m.lasso = cv.glmnet(x.m, y.m, 
                      family = "binomial", 
                      alpha = 1,
                      type.measure = "class")
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    plot(cvfit.m.lasso, main = "Lasso")
    coef(cvfit.m.lasso, s = "lambda.min")
    predTrain.M = predict(cvfit.m.lasso, newx=cv.m, type="class")
    table(cv$NPL, predTrain.M)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed for me now. It was because I forgot to remove my Target variable from the test data , and that is why i was getting this error.

Comment: didn't fix it for me.  It should be matching on column names

Answer (score 0):

> predict(cvFit, newx= x1[1:5], s= "lambda.min")

Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta :
Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90

> View(x1)
> predict(cvFit, newx= x1[**1:5,**], s= "lambda.min")

Maybe it's because your newx didn't include all your preditictive variables used to build your model.
I change my code newx = x[1:5] to newx = x[1:5,], and it worked.
Give it a try?